# Opengl superbible 5th edition code problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I've started reading superbible 5th edition and I'm stuck at the first program. As I'm using xp & vs2008, I've followed all the instruction provided by the book to setup the vs2008 to run the triangle program, but after compilation process it shows an error and I've no idea why is this happenning. The program is following:

```
// Triangle.cpp
// Our first OpenGL program that will just draw a triangle on the screen.

#include <GLTools.h> // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLShaderManager.h> // Shader Manager Class

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h> // OS X version of GLUT
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h> // Windows FreeGlut equivalent
#endif
GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context.
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
{
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();
    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();
    // Perform the buffer swap to display the back buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**And the error displaying is this**

```
1>d:\opengl\SB5\freeglut-2.6.0\VisualStudio2008Static\Release\freeglut_static.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x3
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\dfdf\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
```

Could somebody please help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you made sure you have d:\opengl\SB5\freeglut-2.6.0\VisualStudio2008Static\Release\freeglut_static.lib ?

Comment: Are you using the LIB or the DLL? I've mistyped that dozens of times and it causes just that issue (your error lists the LIB, but are you sure it's actually that, and the right file, etc?)

Comment: LIB as instructed in the book

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lays somewhere else than code. I've traced back what is

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
```

doing and this popped out:

```
#   ifdef FREEGLUT_STATIC

#       define FGAPI
#       define FGAPIENTRY

        /* Link with Win32 static freeglut lib */
#       if FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS
#           pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static.lib")
#       endif
```

However if you downloaded prepared package from [freeglut Windows Development Libraries](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/), you get only freeglut.lib. So either you have to build "freeglut_static.lib" for yourself from freeglut, or don't use static macro and you should be fine. Linker is just saying what it's experiencing - can't find your file so not able to read...

and BTW: What book instructs is one thing but maybe you skipped something or they just didn't included it, but when you download clean freeglut, VisualStudio2008Static folder doesn't contain any library just another folders and visual studio project. You need to open that project, select release version in MSVC (build-> configuration manager) and build project. You get you freeglut_static.lib in release folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting indicates that the freeglut_static.lib file is corrupt. You would be best off to reinstall the library to ensure the file was copied correctly, or you could try rebuilding the library from source.

It might be worth trying a prebuilt version from another website, maybe you'll have more luck with the Visual Studio version available [here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/).

Comment: I've downloaded the freeglut from superbible official website

Comment: Well, why not download the library from the library's homepage http://freeglut.sf.net and compile it from source yourself. That way you ensure that linked library and compiler match.

Comment: freeglut is allright,one of my friend is using this with no problem

Comment: There's not much else you can do, the only reason you get the error [LNK1107](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6ctxtk.aspx) is because you're trying to link the .dll instead of the .lib or the library file is corrupt/unreadable. You're passing the correct file so the only alternative is that the file is not readable by your compiler. The only option you have is to rebuild the library.